# Can I use .less in link element href cross-browser?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, cross-browser, less, bundling-and-minification

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application using [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) and [bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

When my CSS is optimised I get a `link` such as:

```
<link href="/bundles/global.css?v=xxxxx" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

However, when optimisation is disabled I get:

```
<link href="/css/header.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/css/content.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/css/footer.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

In Chrome these `less` files are read just fine.

However, is it common practice to use `.less` files directly as stylesheets?

I'm concerned that some browsers might not recognise the stylesheets as they don't end in `.css` and therefore will ignore them.

**UPDATE:** For clarification, the `.less` files are pre-compiled server side and therefore are valid CSS files. No client-side processing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure as long as the user has Javascript enabled then the only thing that will process and interpret the `.less` files into CSS is the `less.js` library. You could also check their [Browser Support](http://lesscss.org/usage/#browser-support).

I also wouldn't suggest using LESS in production as it's whole purpose is to help you create dynamic stylesheets even faster than normal in development. If you leave it in production then each time the browser loads the page it will have to download the less files and render them which is more time consuming than simply compiling your files into one `.css` file.

**Edit:**

You could ensure that the browser doesn't reject your file and treats your less file as a css file by setting the MIME type on your server to `text/css` for files with the `.less` extension.

For example if you're using Apache you could use the following .htaccess file to do so.

```
AddType text/css .less
```

Comment: I'm not processing LESS on the client side. It's processed server-side using dotless. The contents of the `.less` file is valid CSS.

Comment: Sorry my original answer was completely off. I updated my answer.